# let $a \in A$ and be limits point of $A^+:=\{x\in A :x>a \}$ let $f:A\subset \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb R$ and $a \in A$. Further let $A^+:=\{x\in A :x>a \}$ and $f:A \to \mathbb{R}$.

Assume that $$f'(a+)=\lim_{x\to a^+}\dfrac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}\neq \pm \infty$$
exists. Can we conclude that $f'(a+)=c\in\mathbb{R}$ always holds?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1):

If I interpret your question rightly the answer is no. Consider $A = \{\frac 1 n \mid n \in \mathbb N\}$ and the function
$$ f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R, x \mapsto \begin{cases} x, \quad \text{if }  x \in A \\ 0, \quad \text{else }
\end{cases}.$$
Then you can check that $$\lim_{\substack{x \to 0+ \\ x \in A^+}} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x - 0} = \lim_{\substack{x \to 0+ \\ x \in A^+}}\frac{x}{x} = 1.$$
But the right hand side derivative $f'(0+)$ doesn't even exists because you also got
$$\lim_{\substack{x \to 0+ \\ x \not \in A^+}} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x - 0} = \lim_{\substack{x \to 0+ \\ x \not \in A^+}} \frac{0}{x} = 0.$$

I hope that is what you wanted to know then :)

Comment: Sorry i edited. Do you always $f'(a+)=c \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: I edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Take $f(x) = x \sin \frac{1}{x}$ with $f(0) =0$, and $a=0$